# CodeIgniter 500 Internal Server Error and Blank Page

Tags: php, codeigniter, iis, iis-7

I have just deployed my CodeIgniter application on to a live Windows ISS7 server, tried to access my root page and all I am getting is blank white. Firebug is telling me it's a '500 Internal Server Error'.

The site worked fine on my development server (linux).

When I echo 'hello' in index.php it displays the text, which suggests the server won't load the controllers.

I have no experience using Windows servers unfortunately, and it's not my choice to use it! How can I access some sort of error log?

Any ideas on how I can at least see what the issue is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following line to find where the php error log file is located :

```
phpinfo();
```

Answer (score 1):

**ANSWER**

Sorry, this is ridiculous. I had PHP errors switched off, thanks to adrien for the inspiration to look at the PHP info.

The error was an SVN conflict which had written < < < mine etc in my database file.

Sorry, such a simple error. Thanks.